# how to solve Null pointer exception on Getting latitude or GPS?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get current long, lat. I am getting a Nullpointer on 
`LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

```
    LocationListener myLocationListener = new CurrentLocationListener(); 
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, myLocationListener);
    Location currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps"); 
    Latitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();  ----->>> null pointer exception here
    Longitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();

public class CurrentLocationListener implements LocationListener{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle arg2) {
    }
}
```

My manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: currentLocation is obviously being returned as null. Suggest you fix that...

Comment: actually i am new to this field could you please guide me what should i do to solve this issue? 
yes it is null..

Comment: Do you use the emulator or an actual device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got the answer myself...

[How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-get-gps-location-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

This is usually because there's no last know location. To force obtaining the location you can register for location updates and wait or you can launch **google maps** application, obtain the location using *Menu -> My Location*, return to your application and last know location shouldn't be null.

Comment: could you please elebrate this what does it mean menu-> my location so that i could solve this problem?

Comment: (touch) google maps app (icon) -> (press) Menu (button) -> (touch) My Location (icon)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the right permissions in the manifest file? Something like:

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of obvious ...

```
Location currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps"); 

if (currentLocation != null)
{
    Latitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
    Longitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
}
```

Now, about WHY locationManager is returning a null references instead of an actual Location reference ... It's difficult to know with the code provided. Could be anything.

**Edit:** Mmm, seems like it could be that you have [no gps fix yet](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg13812.html).

Comment: do i need to install something else to activate gps??

Comment: From the emulator, when running, go to your DDMS perspective(it's called like this right?), select the 'Emulator Control' tab and you will see a 'Location Control' part where you can send latitude/longitude positions